# What is the Regex for NUMERIC(p,s) in java

Tags: java, regex

Want a regex for NUMERIC(p,s) NUMERIC will always be there and I just want to check whether inside brackets my values are in decimal or not.
For example NUMERIC(10.20), so my regex would also contains "NUMERIC(" and decimal checking and ")"

I have tried for decimal check but not able to get the NUMERIC with "(" and ")" in my regex 
"^\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*$"

```
      private boolean getRegex() {
            String valueType="NUMERIC(10.78)";
    String regex = "^NUMERIC(\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*$)";
    return valueType.matches(regex);
}
```

Expected result is the regex which would give me true for any decimal value within "NUMERIC(" and ")"

Comment: 1) You need to escape the parenthesis `()` --- 2) `NUMERIC(10.20)` is invalid, since `p` and `s` must be separated by comma, not period. It is not a decimal point, subject to locale. --- 3) ` ? true : false` is redundant, The expression before `?` is already a boolean value.

Comment: NUMERIC(p,s) is precision and scale so this is with decimal like NUMERIC(10.20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `^NUMERIC(\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*$)` has some small issues. You need to escape `(` and write them as `\(` similarly `)` as `\)`. Next I don't think you need alternation as you want to match only decimal values hence for that you can write it like this `\d*\.\d+` as this would match optional digits before the decimal and since the value has to be a decimal, there needs to be at least one digit after `.` hence `\d+` will be needed. You can use this regex,

```
^NUMERIC\(\d+\.\d+\)$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rzkVY/2)**

Java codes,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("NUMERIC(10.78)","NUMERIC(.78)","NUMERIC(1078)");
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " --> "+x.matches("^NUMERIC\\(\\d+\\.\\d+\\)$")));
```

Prints,

```
NUMERIC(10.78) --> true
NUMERIC(.78) --> false
NUMERIC(1078) --> false
```

Comment: I also want validation of NUMERIC(.78) --> false
as i want NUMERIC(10.78) -->true or atleast single digit before decimal

Comment: @Shubhamkapoor: So you want that there should be at least one digit before decimal too? Just need to change `\d*` before decimal to `\d+`. Updated my answer. Check and let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Thanks for helping me